# Sabre InstaFlights Search 404 not found "errorCode": "WARN.RAF.APPLICATION",

Tags: api, sabre

Sabre InstaFlights Search, can any one advice i am getting 404 not found respond upon trying InstaFlights Search on Sabre API explorer.

Comment: Currently it is working fine for me. Are you still having issues? Can you share your request?

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing using the Sabre API Explorer against the Sandbox environment, keep in mind this may have limited support City Pair Airports with test data.

To get a list of our supported city pairs of origin and destination airports, use the City Pairs Lookup API in API Explorer. You can pass any of these origin and destination airport codes in an InstaFlights Search API request.